# List doesn't contain its floated list items

Tags: html, css, css-float

In the following code the ul is not shown. It's like the li's need to be cleared, but I can't do that because I have other floats that it would mess with. Why doesn't the ul enclose its li's and is there a way to make it work? (I've only tested it in Firefox)

```
<style>
   li { float: left; }
   ul { background: #F00; }
</style>

<ul>
   <li>One</li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No container will surround floated items by default. This is normal behavior, not something special for ul/li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really easy:

- Add `overflow: auto` to the `ul` rule.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/CAMMJ/)

I'm not sure what you mean by "but I can't do that because I have other floats that it would mess with" - you'll need to show more of your code and describe what you want a bit better.

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks. It seems a little weird that you have to add that is there a reason for that? And I didn't know if I should have used clear:left; somewhere, but that would mess up the other floats on the page, but that doesn't matter now, overflow: auto worked perfect

Comment: The reason is a problem known as ["clearing floats"](http://www.google.com/search?q=clearing+floats). There's a plethora of articles about it on the internet, [this one](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) looks like a clear explanation.

Comment: Yep, I've read about clearing floats I was just eliminating that as a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can't link to a demo at the moment, but I think adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `ul`'s CSS should work.

Comment: It does work. Is there any particular reason you would want to use `overflow: hidden` compared to `overflow: auto`?

Comment: In the link you sent me it said some of the very old browsers will always display scroll bars for elements with overflow: auto;

Comment: @thirtydot, @Rob: sorry it's taken me so long to respond, but as Rob notes there are issues (such as the ever-present scroll-bars) that reduce the aesthetic use of `auto`. But that's the only reason that *I* prefer to use `hidden` instead of `auto`.