# Force ul to contain floated list items: use &nbsp or overflow: auto?

Tags: html, css

I don't wan't to use clearfix on all the parents above, because that would mess up my layout.

What is the best way and the correct way to do this?

I added a nbsp; after the last li and everything worked perfectly. No need for clearfix spamming. But is this the "correct" way to do it?

Edit: I've just seen [List doesn't contain its floated list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642227/list-doesnt-contain-its-floated-list-items).

So my new question is: what's better, &nbsp or adding overflow: auto?

Comment: You could always just add `overflow: auto;` to the `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `overflow: auto` <strike>or `overflow: visible`</strike> is obviously the better way but a concern may be that it may not render correctly in all browsers (*cough* Internet Explorer *cough*) with different rendering engines, etc.

In reality, if using `&nbsp;` works, then use it.

A good article to read about floats is [this one](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/)

**EDIT**: Don't use `overflow:visible`, that was just silly of me to suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

You could us `display:inline-block;` to achieve the same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/w7U26/